# Wordpress hooks after a post is saved

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been searching and found a lot of various answers, however, I have not found a definitive answer.

I need to run a function right after a post is done saving to the database. This includes every aspect of the post including post metas. I have tried to hook into save_post but that seems to run my function before post metas are saved. I have also tried post_updated and updated_postmeta, but my function doesn't seem to run on either of them.

Another thing to note, I need to have access to the post ID inside my function.

**Edit,** My plugin uses the Advanced Custom Fields plugin and the function I have coded uses update_field to either create new post metas or update existing one based on some stuff. This code works. When I run the function at the post_updated hook the function seems to run but nothing happens. If I add die() to the end of my function my code works, but die kills the page and all I am left with is a blank white page at the url wp-admin/post.php. So adding die allows my function to work and I am not sure why it would not work without die.

Comment: Have you tried post_update with a die() inside your function ? https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/post_updated

Comment: I put that hook in my post.

Comment: Yes, but with a die(). Sometime there are redirections and you will never see the var_dump. And publish_post  hook ? It is triggered when publish new post or update post

Comment: See this thread : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/192258/execute-action-after-post-is-saved-with-all-related-post-meta-records-data

Comment: OK I added the die() and that seems to have worked but at the same time that die() kills the page after my function is ran and I just get a blank white page.

Comment: publish_post doesnt seem to do anything either.So post_updated worked but only when I add die(), but adding die() makes the page stop loading

Comment: Nope the die is just for you to know that your hook is working. Just use the die for the time you develop the functionnality. When you think everything is OK, remove the die.

Comment: Sometimes when you think things are not working it's just because there are other scripts that pass over yours, or because there is a redirection.
Example : If you do a var_dump on a page, but just after that wordpress is redirecting you to another page, you will never see the var dump. This is why die() is very useful. If your page is broken, it means that your functions works.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: Can you give us your code ? I have advanded custom field, i can test it now.

Answer (score 1):

I would comment your post, but I cannot because I dont have 50 rep.

Do you mean the_post?
https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/the_post

```
function my_the_post_action( $post_object ) {
    // modify post object here
}
add_action( 'the_post', 'my_the_post_action' );
```

it ought to have the post Id

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_post/

Comment: Nope this one is triggered when te front page is rendering. He needs a hook just after the post has been saved in DB.

Comment: Additionally hes mentioning the hooks that run after a post is saved, but he is saying they run before the post meta is updated.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I found how to make `publish_post` work.

For custom post type you need to replace the "post" by the post type slug.

Example with the custom post type "Recipe" with "recipe" slug.

```
add_action('publish_recipe', 'test_publish_post', 10, 2);
function test_publish_post($post_id, $post){

    wp_die($post_id);
}
```

**Don't forget to `wp_die()` or `die()`;** else you will be redirected and you won't see your `var_dump();`

Answer (score 1):

I was able to
 fix my issue. It turns out that save_post does seem to run after post metas are saved. My problem actually came from something else inside my code that I was able to fix by changing how I handled that part of my script.