# How to get woocommerce product all details when publish a new product?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-hook

I want to fetch woocommerce product post data when we publish a new product. I've tried some hooks but it's working only when we update the product.
Does anyone knows how  can I get the product post data when adding new product?

Here is my code.

```
add_action( 'save_post_product',  'add_product_tocrm_through_woocommerce', 10, 3);
function add_product_tocrm_through_woocommerce($post_id, $post, $update){

    if ( wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if (!$product = wc_get_product( $post )) {
        return;
    }

    $post_type = get_post_type( $post_id );
    $post_status = get_post_status();

    if ( $post_type == 'product' && $post_status == 'publish') {

        $product = wc_get_product($post_id);
        $pNameWoo =   $product->name;
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $desc =  $product->get_description();

        $wooProduct[0]['name'] = $pNameWoo;
        $wooProduct[0]['price'] = $price;
        $wooProduct[0]['description'] = $desc;
        save_woo_product_tocrm($wooProduct);
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe this help-> [what is a wordpress/woocommerce hook tha fire after a woocommerce product saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997189/what-is-a-wordpress-woocommerce-hook-tha-fire-after-a-woocommerce-product-saved)

Comment: Thanks @AndyTschiersch  for your help. I got  the solution using woocommerce_process_product_meta hook with priority 20 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution using woocommerce_process_product_meta hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'add_product_tocrm_through_woocommerce', 99, 2);
if (!function_exists('add_product_tocrm_through_woocommerce')) {
    function add_product_tocrm_through_woocommerce($product_id, $update)
    {
        $post_type = get_post_type( $product_id );
        $post_status = get_post_status($product_id);

        if ($post_status == 'publish' && !$update) {
            $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
            print_r($product);
            $pNameWoo =   $product->get_name();
            $desc =  $product->get_description();
            $price =  $product->get_regular_price();
            $sale_price =  $product->get_sale_price();
            
            $wooProduct['name'] = $pNameWoo;
            $wooProduct['price'] = $price;
            $wooProduct['sale_price'] = $sale_price;
            $wooProduct['description'] = $desc;
            $wooProduct['pid'] = $product_id;
            save_woo_product_tocrm($wooProduct);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using "save_post_product" hook, so you don't need to check lots of things before triggering your CRM save function.

Also, you need to use "->get_name()" instead of "->name" and the long description cannot be gotten in the way you coded, but with $post->post_content instead:

```
add_action( 'save_post_product', 'add_product_tocrm_through_woocommerce', 9999, 3 );

function add_product_tocrm_through_woocommerce( $post_id, $post, $update ){
    if ( ! $update ) { // ONLY TARGET NEW PRODUCTS
        $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
        $pNameWoo = $product->get_name();
        $price = $product->get_price();
        $desc = $post->post_content;
        $wooProduct[0]['name'] = $pNameWoo;
        $wooProduct[0]['price'] = $price;
        $wooProduct[0]['description'] = $desc;
        save_woo_product_tocrm($wooProduct);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion.
i am not getting product post data when i publish the product. 
is there anyway to pull the fields data of product post on adding a new product?

Comment: i have tried your code but still i am not getting the data of product.

Comment: Well, it should work. Sure save_woo_product_tocrm() is properly coded?

Comment: yeah it's properly coded and tested. I am sending that data using RESTapi to SuiteCRM and the function working properly.
do we have access to the $post_id and $post data? I think  when we publish the **product**  product id and post data isn't generated.  and after publishing the product we have that data.
that's why I am asking that is there anyway to get all the fields data??

or may be I'm wrong about this so please suggest any solution for this?

**off topic** :- I have learned a lot from your blogs on your website.  Thanks :-)